# Pink lines around windows on Windows 10 Anniversary

Tags: windows-10

Since updating to the windows 10 anniversary I now have these strange lines of pink around every windows that isn't maximised.
I found on Reddit that someone else is having the same issue as me, but there have been no replies to their problem, just wondering if anyone else is experiencing the same problem?
[image]

As you can see, I'm downloading the ATI 5650m graphics driver for Windows 10 to see if this fixes my annoying problem.

Answer (score 2):

The main accent color determines the border color.

Open settings. Go to Personalization. Select Colors and pick a blue or a black.

[image: Pink]